# Join five mysql tables for search

Tags: php, search, mysqli, sql-like, join

Please check the images:

file table:

[image]

conference table:

[image]

journal table:

[image]

project_thesis table

[image]

research table

[image]

I am making a file upload site where students can upload journal/research/conference paper. The file table contains the file name. I want to join these all tables together to use for search feature, where students can search documents based on title, keywords or author name or abstract.

Could you please tell me how to join these tables and use search using LIKE? File_id is unique and foreign key in all other tables. The title, keyword, abstract are in all tables.

Comment: Hi Lee. I've edited your question so the images are visible to readers, however in future these would be better as text - one can export table formats from phpMyAdmin very easily.

Comment: Also, you may not be familiar with the way Stack Overflow works. We generally encourage people to add an attempt into their question, for two reasons. Firstly it shows readers the intended direction of the question, so an answer does not go off on a tangent that the asker did not intend. Secondly, when a person tries to answer a question that they do not know how to solve, they will often learn something. In this case, there are many examples of SQL joins on this site, and in the MySQL manual. Would you give it a go?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit and reply . I appreciate it . I am a newbie. i Watched couple of videos on youtube , but none worked. I will try to study more and i will update here . kind regards .Lee

Comment: Make a start by joining two tables, and run the code in phpMyAdmin in the SQL window. I like to edit it in a text editor, and paste it in, so I don't lose it. Then when that works, add in a new table, until all tables are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join your table based on file_id in the following way.And you can also search by id.just putting your search id at Your_search_file_id place.

```
select *from conference 
inner join  journal on conference.file_id =journal.file_id
inner join  project_thesis on project_thesis.file_id =journal.file_id
inner join  research on research.file_id =journal.file_id
where journal.file_id = Your_search_file_id;
```

Comment: As per my remarks under the question, we often try to encourage answerers to wait until some effort has been made on the problem. Supplying answers where no attempt has been made is immediately helpful, but waiting for the OP to give it a go may help them in the longer term to become a better programmer.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (file AS file INNER JOIN project_thesis AS project_thesis ON (file.file_id = project_thesis.file_id )) WHERE ( file.file_id = project_thesis.file_id )

Comment: this joins the project thesis and and file based on file . But i need all the journal,research,reasearch,conference included in as well . How do i do that ?

Comment: When you will the query i send you , you will get all the segment in one place as you have used code inner join.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from conference inner join journal on conference.file_id =journal.file_id in' at line 1

Comment: place a space in between * & form hope it will work . if still not working then can you upload it to sqlfiddle or any place so i that i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

After learning a bit I understood that these tables are not formed correctly . So there is no right answer to this question